# Azure VM is down after installation of purevpn app

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I tried to install purevpn windows app on my azure iis vm (the app allows me to connect to a proxy. I did not sign in to the app at that point). suddenly my rdp connection was lost and I could not reconnect. all http access to my apps on the server return time out. on azure dashboard i see that for some reason the public ip is changed. trying to go directly to the ip return time out as well.

can anyone share something that I can do?

## Edit After contacting Azure support:

## ISSUE

cannot RDP to classic VM

## INVESTIGATION

found VM landed in normal logon screen

per Guest log, found public firewall profile blocking all connections

PublicProfile-DoNotAllowExceptions 1 NotSet This profile is set to "Block all connections"

## ROOT CAUSE

3rd party PureVPN is blocking all connection

## RESOLUTION

found no Guest agent is installed, hence have to delete VM, attach disk to edit registry to disable public firewall profile

followed plan:

1. reserved public IP via PowerShell
   New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "webserver" -Location "West Europe" -ServiceName "MIS-WebServer"
2. saved VM config from resources.azure.com
3. deleted VM, attach disk to another working VM
   loaded SYSTEM hive and changed reg key from 1 to 0 to have public firewall profile disabled
4. rebuilt VM and now it’s good taking RDP

Comment: Hi,@Shlo, I tested this solution in my lab early but I think it  just changed the firewall to open RDP and cost a lot of time. I suggest my answer be the best solution to resolve this kind trouble that cannot RDP to Azure VM because of the firewall inside the VM blocking the RDP port.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue with install the PureVPN on my Azure VM. I saw my RDP disconnection when the PureVPN install program updating the firewall policy. So, I did this test and find it is caused by the default firewall configuration has been changed and block  all inbound connections through Public Network.(My VM Public IP wasn't changed)

You can take this solution as following steps:

1. Open up a Blank Notepad and paste the following into it:

`Set-NetFirewallProfile -Name public -AllowInboundRules True`

2. Save the file as configfirewall.ps1
3. Navigate to the Azure Portal
4. Select the impacted VM
5. Select extensions

   [image]
6. Select Add
7. Select Custom Script Extension

[image]

8. Select Create
9. Select the disablefirewall.ps1 created in the previous steps
10. Install the .ps1 file. No arguments are needed.

[image]

11. Go back to the extensions tab and wait for the Custom Script to report as successful

12.Attempt to RDP to the machine. If it fails, restart the VM and attempt to RDP to it again.

After RDP to your VM, you can check your firewall status . Then you can try to use the VPN APP. If it not work, you can look for more professional VPN APP support from the PureVPN official support.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne. I contact Azure support and the problem was indeed with the firewall. I didn't try your solution so I cannot mark as "accepted" though your solution seems to be easier and more straight forward than the one performed by azure support agent. The ip change was since I used "stop" and "start" instead of just "restart" the VM. I will provide the solution performed by the support agent for future reference.

Comment: Hi,@Shlo, you can just have a try.I did use an Azure VM and install the PureVPN APP. What I post here is most simple and esay solution.I'm sure it will work for you. If you can try this and mark it ,you will help more users who came across it.